# Calculating s in ECDSA over GF(2m)

Tags: diffie-hellman, bignum

I tried to calculate s over GF(m) as integer, but it is not working since the integer in vhdl has limit size, especially since you're working with 2^163.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Year ago I've implemented very big numbers with VHDL there is no limit other than the physical... Unfortunately, this question is about a programming issue and doesn't belong to here. This question might fits to  [electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl).

Comment: You'll probably want/need to edit your title/question to ask "How to implement bignums in VHDL" rather than asking about ECDSA, but since that's a substantial edit I can't do that for you.

Comment: This shouldn't have been migrated.